# Cannot get sinch call when app is clear from recent in android

Tags: java

Cannot get sinch call when app is clear from recent in android

```
public class SinchService extends Service {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "clientapi.sinch.com";

    public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
    static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

    private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient mSinchClient;
    private String mUserId;

    private StartFailedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    private void start(String userName) {
        Log.d("start123", "start");
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mUserId = userName;
            mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(userName)
                    .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                    .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                    .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();
            mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);
            mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
            mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
            mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
            mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
            mSinchClient.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mSinchServiceInterface;
    }

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public Call callUserVideo(String userId) {

            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId);
        }
        public Call callUser(String userId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUserVideo(userId);
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return mUserId;
        }

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            start(userName);
        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public Call getCall(String callId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
        }

        public VideoController getVideoController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getVideoController();
        }

        public AudioController getAudioController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getAudioController();
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {

        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                                                      ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }

    private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {

            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference cal = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("call_detail").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(call.getCallId());

            cal.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String cl = dataSnapshot.child("callType").getValue(String.class);

                        if( cl.equals("audio") ){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingVoiceCallActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
                            intent.putExtra("callerUserId", call.getRemoteUserId());
                            Log.d("ABCD", call.getRemoteUserId());

                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);

                        }if (cl.equals("video")){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingVideoCallActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
                            intent.putExtra("callerUserId", call.getRemoteUserId());
                            Log.d("ABCD", call.getRemoteUserId());

                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I received call when app is in recent tray. but when i clear app from recent i cannot get call.  this is my SinchService class. i also used forground service, with foreground service i get call on some devices on app close but not get call on some oppo and samsung mobiles.